# sequelizejs eager fetch many to many

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to fetch eager on a join table in Nodejs with Sequelizejs v3 .

So, 1 Tag can belong to Many Images, and Many Images can have multiple tags.

Tag 1 - > M ImageTag M < - 1 Image

I am getting `Unhandled rejection Error: Tag is not associated to ImageDetails` when i tried to excute a query.

```
function getImagesFromAlbum(albumid, callback, errCallback){
  ImageDetails.findAll({where: { AlbumId: albumid }, include: [{model: Tag}]}).then((data) => {
    return callback(data)
  }).catch((err) => {
    return errCallback(err)
  })
}
```

The expected return result should be the data according to the albumid, with the assiociate tags for that image

Here are the relationship joining

```
ImageDetails.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: { singular: "tag", plural: "tags" }, through: { model: ImageTag, unique: false }, foreignKey: "ImageId"})
Tag.belongsToMany(ImageDetails, { as: { singular: "image", plural: "images" }, through: { model: ImageTag, unique: false },  foreignKey: "TagId"})
```

Here are the model designs

> Tag Model

```
const model = {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
}

const name = "Tag"
```

> ImageTag model (Join Table)

```
const model = {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
}
const name = "ImageTag"
```

> ImageDetails model

```
import { Sequelize, db } from "../config/MySqlConfiguration"

const model = {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  ImageLocation: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  originalName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
}

const name = "ImageDetails"
```

*Note sequelize.define is purposely omitted.

Answer (score 0):

When defining relation between models with use of alias (`as`) in the `belongsToMany`, you need to remember to include this alias when eager loading models, so your query would look as follows

```js
ImageDetails.findAll({
    where: { AlbumId: albumid },
    include: [{ model: Tag, as: 'tags' }]
}).then((data) => {
    return callback(data)
}).catch((err) => {
    return errCallback(err)
});
```

And what is the `AlbumId` you want to perform query on? According to your models definition, the `ImageDetails` model does not have such a field.